# Calculate Density of Values in Cellular Automata

Tags: functions, dynamical-systems, simulation, cellular-automata

I am working with a special cellular automata that uses hexagonal cells rather than square cells, a hexagonal grid, rather than a square grid, and the set of complex numbers, rather than a finite set, for the cellular state-space. In this case it seems more appropriate to refer to a cell's "value" rather than the cell's "state."

I need to have a way of calculating the density of values in relation to a particular cell, as well as a function that takes a set of cells and produces a density value for the set. The end goal is have a metric for measuring clusters of values for any arbitrary area, possible discontinuous or infinite, of the cellular automata's universe.

---

**Here is my current model:**
$$\mathbf{C}:\mathrm{the\;set\;of\;all\;cells\;}$$
$$Value(x):\mathrm{calculates\;the\;value\;of\;the\;given\;cell,}\;x$$
$$Dist(a,b):\mathrm{calculates\;the\;Manhattan\;distance\;between\;two\;given\;cells,}\;a\;\mathrm{and}\;b$$
$$CellularDensity(x)=\sum_{c\in\mathbf{C}}\frac{Value(c)}{2^{Dist(x,c)}}$$
$$AreaDensity(\mathbf{A})=\sum_{a\in\mathbf{A}}CellularDensity(a)$$

---

**Here is what is wrong with the current model:**

The current model is does not work well when there is an infinite number on cells with non-zero values in the universe, such as when a pattern of values is defined.

I am looking to have this model replaced with something that can produce meaningful density values given a finite area, as defined by a set of cells, when there is an infinite number of cells with non-zero values present.